# How to set latlon in arraylist in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, methods, arraylist

I am building an android application where I am setting latlong on click using arraylist on click. Now I wanna to set hard core latlong onCreateView but there is a problem cannot resolve the variable is set final.

Below is click code -

```
 // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already two locations
                if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /**
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }


                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean that `markerPoints` is declared as `final`? If so, you could remove the `final` keyword...

Comment: Declare the variable as a instance variable (before onCreateView) and initialize it in `onCreateView`